# How to conditionally change colour of button based on a keyword

Tags: css, reactjs

I am wishing to display card's which hold a Bootstrap badge at the top of each card. I would like to conditionally change the colour of the badge depending on status of the pet.

```
render() {
        const isAdmin = true;
        const post = this.props.post; 
        const id = this.props.post.post_ID; 
        console.log(post);


     return (
        <div>

        <Card id="card-main" style={{ width: '18rem', margin: '12px' }}>
        <span class="badge badge-secondary">{post.petStatus}</span>
            <Card.Img id="card-img-top" variant="top" src={post.img_path} />
            <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{post.pet_name}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text id="PetName">
                  <strong>{post.petName} </strong>
                </Card.Text>
                <Card.Text id="content">
                  {post.content} 
                </Card.Text>
                <Card.Text>
                  <strong>Posted By: </strong>{post.name}
                </Card.Text>
                <Card.Text
                  <strong>Posted: </strong>{post.postedOn}
                </Card.Text>

          </Card>
```

Comment: how many ' statuses ' do you have ? or how many colors ? if you have just 2 it's more easy and you can write it inline, if not then you would need a small helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the number of colors your need, you could either do it inline:

```
    <Card id="card-main" style={{ width: '18rem', margin: '12px' }}>
    <span class="badge badge-secondary" style={{color: post.petStatus === "adopted" ? "blue" : "red"}}>{post.petStatus}</span>
```

... or if you need several colors probably better to write a helper that returns a style based on the status:

```
getStyleForStatus = (status)=>{
    let statusColor
    switch (status){
        case "adopted":
            statusColor = "blue"
            break;
        case "lost":
            statusColor = "red"
            break;
        default:
          //
      return {color:statusColor}
    }
}
 render() {
    const isAdmin = true;
    const post = this.props.post; 
    const id = this.props.post.post_ID; 
    console.log(post);


 return (
    <div>

    <Card id="card-main" style={{ width: '18rem', margin: '12px' }}>
    <span class="badge badge-secondary" style={getStyleForStatus(post.petStatus)}>{post.petStatus}</span>

          {/* ... */}

      </Card>
```